# Instructions to make Ubuntu 11 Server work with XenServer?

Tags: ubuntu, xenserver

Does anyone have good instructions on how to make Ubuntu 11 work well on XenServer?  I have two servers setup and would like to make sure that I get them working as well as I can on XenServer.  I am pretty new to running the linux servers but have been running windows servers on XenServer for a couple years now.  So the simpler the instructions the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.  My favorite way is to just grab the image from here, and do a File->Import from XenServer:

http://www.isaaczarb.com/ubuntu-9-10-x64-template-for-xenserver-5-x/

After you do this, you may want to upgrade ubuntu to the latest version with a do-release-upgrade, you can do that following the instructions here:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/upgrade

.
.

If you would like to take the "long route" and install it yourself, here are some instructions for doing that:

http://community.citrix.com/display/xs/Installing+Ubuntu+Server+10.04+(32bit+and+64bit)+LTS

Regards, Port Forward Podcast

http://www.portforwardpodcast.com